# How do I put flexbox navigation bar dropdown items into columns instead of one long column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

I'm building a navigation bar in flexbox with a drowdown menu. My problem is that one of the dropdown items has many sub-items (more than 30) and rather than have then in a single column, I would like to put them in a pre-set number of columns (4, for example). How would I do this?

To clarify, it is the subitems (in my example below, ITEM 3A through ITEM 3T) that I would like to show up in 4 columns (rather than 1 long column) upon hovering over the parent item (ITEM 3, in this case).

Thanks!

Here's my html and css code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Flexbox Navbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbarexample_manyitems.css"
</head>
<body>
  <header>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav_links">
          <li><a href="#">ITEM 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ITEM 2 &#x25BC;</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-1">
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 2A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ITEM 2B</a></li>
                    </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">ITEM 3 &#x25BC;</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-1">
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3A</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3B</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3C</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3D</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3E</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3F</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3G</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3H</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3I</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3J</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3K</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3L</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3M</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3N</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3O</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3P</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3Q</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3R</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3S</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3T</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">ITEM 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ITEM 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ITEM 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #24252A;
}

li,a {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 5%;
}
.nav_links {
  list-style: none;
}
.nav_links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.nav_links li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.nav_links li a:hover {
  color: #fe3fb3;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}
.nav_links li:hover .dropdown-1 > li{
  display: block;
  top: 0;
}
.dropdown-1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 33.333%;
}
.dropdown-1 li {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-1 li:hover {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  /*  width: 100%; */
}
```

Here's the link to a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eoa8Lnu7/1/

Comment: If you want a flex column to wrap it must have a fixed height and have flex wrap applied.

Comment: Thanks. It worked beautifully! I added the following to the dropdown-1 class--

  height: 150px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;